# Python noob question: Polynomial multiplication question

Tags: python

Can someone help me out with my code, the only answer I get is [0,0] for all inputs-:

```
def add_poly(a,b,n):
    p=[]
    
    for i in range((n*2)-2):
        p.append(0)
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        for j in range(0,n-1):
            p[i+j]=(a[i]*b[j])

    return p


n=2
a=[1,3]
b=[0,2]

print(add_poly(a,b,n))
```

Comment: elaborate what are u trying to do with this code in few words for a better help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If `n` is 2, then `for i in range(0,n-1)` will run exactly once, with a value of 0.

Comment: Is this supposed to be polynomial addition or multiplication?

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes. This question is clearly stated, has a code sample that's sufficiently minimal, shows expected inputs and outputs. What is everyone complaining about? That the name of the function is "wrong"?

Comment: Hi, so in the code I am trying to multiply two polynomials a and b of length n by creating index I for  and index j for b. p is supposed to be the product array which I am initializing with n zeroes and the who for loops are supposed to store the values of the product with degree i+j. However, no matter what I input, p is always returned s a zero array

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is that `range` is exclusive on the high bound. To loop over `n` elements, you do `range(n)`, not `range(n - 1)`. That will give you a loop over `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1`.

Another issue is that you're providing redundant information about the size of the polynomials. The degree is already encoded in their length. If you provide `n`, that's redundant information, and may be wrong. E.g., what if you want to multiply a second order polynomial (`n=3`) by a third order (`n=4`)?

Finally, the operation you are attempting to implement seems like multiplication rather than addition.

So here is a sample of how to use `len` to get the order of the polynomials, and `enumerate` to place the elements. You can also preallocate the output list in one line:

```
def mult_poly(a, b):
    p = [0] * (len(a) + len(b) - 1)

    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for j, y in enumerate(b):
            p[i + j] += x * y

    return p
```

Comment: Shouldn't it also be `+=` in the loop? Also, I don't think the `start=1` and then `-1` is right..

Comment: @tobias_k. Thank you for that. This is what happens when I pull an all-nighter :)